# STL set_union with big lists

Tags: c++, stl

there are two

```
list<int> a (4,100);
list<int> b (4,200);
```

I use them as sets thus are sorted and uniqued:

```
a.sort();
a.unique();
b.sort();
b.unique();
```

Now the two list are like the following:

```
a: 100
b: 200
```

Now I calculate the union:

```
list <int> c(a.size() + b.size());
set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin());
```

The result is fine but what I want is not to copy the two lists into another list. Because the list will be very big and do not contain ints for real.

```
set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin());
```

Does not work bot i actually want the result to be in a without calulating a big copy and do

```
a = c;
```

aftterwards. An additional Problem is that if a = b = {100} then the result c is 
{100, 0}!

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `list` like this is almost certainly bad and wrong. What's up with actual `set`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *minimize* copying with a `std::set_difference` followed by `list::merge`. Both are linear operations.

```
std::list<int> a, b, c;

std::set_difference(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(c));
a.merge(c);
```

The `b` list isn't modified and the temporary `c` list is left empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply want [`list::merge`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/merge/)

```
std::list<int> a, b;

a.sort();
a.unique();
b.sort();
b.unique();

a.merge(b);
a.unique();
```

Depending on your actual data it might turn out faster like this

```
a.sort();
b.sort();
a.merge(b);
a.unique();
```

Comment: Because each of the lists was "sort"ed and "unique"d separately, merging them afterwards does not guarantee that the merged list is either sorted or unique. An additional "sort" and "unique" would be necessary on the merged list.

Comment: @SionSheevok Well, you're only **partly** right. It _does_ guarantee that the result is sorted. A `unique` is still required. I can't really look into the requirements by the OP but will add that. Note my +1 with Blastfurnace's answer

Comment: Assuming it's okay to leave `b` empty, your second code snippet is probably the fastest solution for `std::list`.

Comment: My mistake. The STL merge algorithm *is* sorted.

Comment: Although this is the most elegant solution, it is not the most optimal in terms of memory. You can also skip the sorts in the second snippet.

Comment: Note that because you've only used `std::list` member functions this should only perform pointer twiddling and no copying of node contents.

Comment: @ronag: first off, I feel @Blastfurnace's answer is more elegant. I also suspect that of the solutions, this is by far the most memory efficient (because of the way in which `list::merge` operates: intrusively empty-ing list `b`)

Comment: @ronag: `list::merge` doesn't copy the second list but actually splices its nodes into place, leaving the second list empty.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Understood, I missed that. I retract my comments and remove my "improvement" answer. sehe is quite correct.